# What happened to the Soul Vessel in Majula?

Tags: dark-souls-2

Originally in the basement of the Mansion in Majula, there was a chest that contained a Soul Vessel. I have only just jumped back on again, the last time I played being before the "Crown of the Old Iron King" DLC was released, and it has been replaced with what appears to be a blue Longsword.

When did this happen? Was the Soul Vessel swapped out, or is it just a chance to get different items now? Is there anything special about the Longsword (apart from the appearance)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Majula Mansion Chest](http://darksouls2.wikidot.com/majula-mansion) does not only contain a soul vessel, but is where you can get special event weapons/items. Once the event is over the soul vessel will be back, but until then it will be the current reskinned weapon (The Moonlight Longsword).

Comment: Is there anything overly special about the sword itself?

Comment: Nope, just looks pretty.